# Error retrieving SPM repo via Github SSH in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github, ssh-keys, swift-package-manager

In my Xcode project, I have added a Package Dependency for a package of mine that exists in its own private Github repo. To do so, I have added the SSH (.git) url to my Package Dependencies.

In **Xcode Preferences > Accounts**, I have added my Github account and selected SSH along with the **id_github** SSH key option (followed [directions here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to do so):

[image: Github account with id_github SSH key in Xcode Preferences]

However, most times I try to retrieve / update my SPM packages, I get an error for this package's repo:

> git@github.com: my-repo.git: An unknown error occurred. reference
> 'refs/remotes/origin/main' not found (-1)

[image: Error in Xcode when attempting to retrieve SPM package from private repo of mine]

I have tried Resetting Package Caches, deleting derived data, cleaning the Xcode project, quitting Xcode, etc. But I commonly run into this error. How can I properly retrieve this SPM repo to my Xcode project via SSH without any errors?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Very frustrating. For me, it usually helps to reset packages cache, let all dependencies update, then manually update the private package.